# Gradle can't build native image

Tags: java, gradle, graalvm

I am trying to build a native image via gradle but it can't do it.

`./gradle nativeCompile` fails with an error

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':nativeCompile'.
>
> > Determining GraalVM installation failed with message: 'gu' tool wasn't found. This probably means that JDK at isn't a GraalVM
> > distribution.
> > Make sure to declare the GRAALVM_HOME environment variable or install GraalVM with native-image in a standard location recognized by
> > Gradle Java toolchain support

What is weird as soon as graalvm is default jdk I am using.

When I print graalvm location

```
echo $GRAALVM_HOME
/home/username/graalvm
```

gu tool is also found via command line

```
which gu
/home/username/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/gu
```

I believe the problem is that installation was made via sdkman. How should I configure native plugin in gradle to make it recognize my installation?

Answer (score 1):

$GRAALVM_HOME was pointing to the wrong dir